# How to get page dots on an Apple Watch project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

For my Apple Watch project, I'd like to be able to swipe between different page views, and have page dots at the bottom of the screen. How do I do this in Xcode? I've tried everything and I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

use `next-page` segue to implement the page based navigation.
refer to this tutorial

> http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-page-based-navigation/

also tho this apple developer forum page

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html